# How do I fix line spacing in Notepad++?

Tags: fonts, notepad++, line-spacing

I used CCleaner on my pc and restarted.

After I restarted I opened Notepad++ and was told that config.xml was gone.

Afterwards, my previous opened .txt document was opened but the font and spacing was all wrong. I was able to fix font but not the spacing.

The new spacing is:

[image]

and I want it changed back to:

[image]

I tried Settings -> Preferences -> Editing but no luck.

Answer (score 18):

To change the line spacing go to **Settings** → **Style Configurator**.

On the left select **Global Styles** under Language then **Brace Highlight Style** under Style and then change the **Font size**.

[image]

Comment: Similar answer, but with animated picture: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32284964/873282

Comment: This option has a really strange name, I could never have figured this out. Thanks.

Comment: I think that setting's font size was meant to be empty (top entry in Font size dropdown). Then the line spacing will follow font size in Default Style. I added an answer reflecting that.

Answer (score 7):

This fix wouldn't work for me, so I kept trying and I found what would work for me in the Settings>Style Configurator>Language: Global Style in the left field and Style: Line Number Margin' in the right field; from there, just change the font size on the far right.

Comment: Didn't help here with size <= 7pt. The answer by @Ayan helped me.

Comment: Helped me. nice work around!

Comment: this trick works on me, I choose the size on Line Number Margin bigger than my font size, and it works

Comment: I found that setting both "Line number margin" and "Brace highlight style" to have Font Size empty (the top entry in dropdown), made it so line spacing would follow the font size I set in "Default Style".

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answers by Ayan and Myrtle, I think what's happening is Style settings with **Font size** set to a number will force the line spacing to a *minimum* of that size, which makes no sense for some settings. If you go through the Style settings, you will see most have nothing in the box for **Font size**.

What you want is to clear the sizes from settings that should not have them, that way the font size specified under **Default Style** will control the *line spacing* as well as *font size*. Go to **Language** Global Styles → **Style** Brace highlight style. In the **Font size** box, click on the dropdown and note the top entry in the list is *blank*. Select that; now the box should be empty and it will not affect the line spacing. I think the default style is not meant to have a number there. Do the same for **Style** Line number margin.

Now go to **Style** Default Style. As you change **Font size** you should see the line spacing follow the font size correctly.