# Shrink line height in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, fonts, styles

To increase the line height in Notepad++ you can change the Brace Highlight Style or the Line Number Margin to a larger font size as described here:

[How do I fix line spacing in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/886166/how-do-i-fix-line-spacing-in-notepad)

But changing to a smaller font size does not decrease the line height. Is there a way to shrink the line height for a given font size?